# Determining different elements in a d3.js SVG group on drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I am trying to drag a line from one SVG group and drop it on another. On the SVG group I drop on to, I want to be able to determine what part of that group I am dropping to.

I have some code:

HTML:

```
<div id="MainDiv">
```

CSS:

```
.analogDrag {
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var startX, startY, linkX, linkY, t;
var selectedNode = null,
  startNode = null,
  endNode = null;

function startHandler(d) {
  startNode = null;
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  d3.select(this).style('cursor', 'move');
  this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  endNode = this.id;
  startX = parseInt(d.x) + parseInt(d3.select(this.cx.animVal.value)) + 15;
  startY = parseInt(d.y) + parseInt(d3.select(this.cy.animVal.value));
  linkX = startX;
  linkY = startY;
  startNode = d3.event.sourceEvent.srcElement.parentNode.id;
}

function onDragDrop(dragHandler, dropHandler) {
  var drag = d3.behavior.drag();
  drag.on("drag", dragHandler).on("dragstart", startHandler).on("dragend", dropHandler);
  return drag;
}

function linkDragMove() {
  linkX += d3.event.dx;
  linkY += d3.event.dy;
  d3.selectAll(".link").remove();
  d3.selectAll("svg").append("line").attr("x1", startX).attr("y1", startY).attr("x2", linkX).attr("y2", linkY).attr("stroke", "black").attr("stroke-width", 1).attr("class", "link");
  d3.selectAll(".analogDrag").style('cursor', "default");
  d3.selectAll(".analogDrop").attr("stroke-width", 6).style('cursor', "crosshair");
}

function linkDropHandler(d) {
  d3.select(this).style('cursor', "crosshair");
  d3.selectAll(".analogDrag").style('cursor', "crosshair");
  d3.selectAll(".analogDrop").attr("stroke-width", 1).style('cursor', "default");
  d3.selectAll(".link").remove();
  var x, y;
  var yAdjust = 0;
  if (selectedNode) {
      var n = selectedNode[0][0].attributes;
    if (selectedNode[0][0].id.charAt(0) == "F") yAdjust = 25;
    if (selectedNode[0][0].id.charAt(0) == "K") yAdjust = 40;
    if (selectedNode[0][0].id.charAt(0) == "S") yAdjust = 110;
    for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        if (n[i].name == "transform") {
            var co = n[i].value.match(/[0-9]+/g);
            x = parseInt(co[0]);
            y = parseInt(co[1]) + yAdjust;
            break; //Stop iterating once the named array has been found
        }
    }
    debugger;
    endNode = selectedNode[0][0].id;
    //Check if link already exists.
    var links = d3.selectAll(".Link").filter("." + startNode + "." + endNode);
    if (!links[0][0] || links[0][0].attributes['4'].nodeValue != "Link " + startNode + " " + endNode) { //The link does not already exist
        //Draw line to this node.
        d3.selectAll("svg").append("path").attr("d", "M " + startX + " " + startY + " L " + " " + x + " " + y).attr("fill-opacity", 0).attr("stroke", "black").attr("stroke-width", 1)
            .attr("class", "Link " + startNode + " " + endNode);
    }
}
}

var overNode = function (d) {
  selectedNode = d;
};

var outNode = function () {
  selectedNode = null;
};

var f = function (container) {
  var d = [{
    x: 100,
    y: 0,
    moveX: 0,
    moveY: 0
}];
var functions = container.data(d).append("g").attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}).attr("id", "F1");
functions.append("rect").attr({
    x: 20,
    y: 0,
    width: 125,
    height: 125,
    fill: "#F5F5FF",
    stroke: "black",
        "stroke-width": 1,
    id: "highlight"
});
functions.append("path").attr({
    "d": "M 20,10 a10,15 0 0,0 0,30",
    fill: "#FFFFFF",
    stroke: "black",
        "stroke-width": 1,
        "class": "analogDrop"
}).on("mouseover", function () {
    overNode(functions);
}).on("mouseout", function () {
    outNode();
});
functions.append("line").attr({
    x1: 0,
    y1: 25,
    x2: 20,
    y2: 25,
    stroke: "black",
        "stroke-width": 1,
        "class": "analogDrop"
}).on("mouseover", function () {
    overNode(functions);
}).on("mouseout", function () {
    outNode();
});
functions.append("path").attr({
    "d": "M 20,80 a10,15 0 0,0 0,30",
    fill: "#FFFFFF",
    stroke: "black",
        "stroke-width": 1,
        "class": "analogDrop"
}).on("mouseover", function () {
    overNode(functions);
}).on("mouseout", function () {
    outNode();
});
functions.append("line").attr({
    x1: 0,
    y1: 95,
    x2: 20,
    y2: 95,
    stroke: "black",
        "stroke-width": 1,
        "class": "analogDrop"
}).on("mouseover", function () {
    overNode(functions);
}).on("mouseout", function () {
    outNode();
});
};

var k = function (container) {
  var d = [{
    x: 0,
    y: 25,
    moveX: 0,
    moveY: 0
}];
var kn = container.data(d).append("g").attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
})
    .attr("id", "K1");
kn.append("circle").attr({
    cx: 0,
    cy: 0,
    r: 15,
    stroke: "black",
        "stroke-width": 2,
    fill: "#FFFFFF",
        "class": "analogDrag"
}).call(onDragDrop(linkDragMove, linkDropHandler));
};
d3.selectAll("svg").remove();
var svgContainer = d3.select("#MainDiv").append("svg").attr("width", 800).attr("height", 600).attr("version", 1.1).attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg").attr("viewBox", "-40, -40, 1600, 1200");
f(svgContainer);
k(svgContainer);
```

I also have a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Family/x17hxgus/

So I can drag from the circle node to the two links on the square node, but I can't find a way to determine which of the links I drop to.

The only way I have found of determining which group I have dropped to is 'selectedNode[0][0].id', but I need more information than that.

Can anyone help me in the right direction, please?

EDIT

The jsfiddle works in Chrome and Firefox, it doesn't work in IE.

Comment: i would check where the cursor is on 'mouseup' after you drop the line and check if its in on top of one of the links. To do this id create an invisible rectangle over each area you wish to check over so then rather than checking the exact point, you just check if the cursor (when you dropped the line) is in that rectangle. You could even use this logic so the line snaps to the closest link when letting go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you have is close.  Redefine your `overNode` and `outNode` as:

```
var selectedNode = null;
var overNode = function () {
    selectedNode = this; 
};
var outNode = function () {
    selectedNode = null;
};
```

And then call them as:

```
functions.append("path").attr({
    "d": "M 20,80 a10,15 0 0,0 0,30",
    fill: "#FFFFFF",
    stroke: "black",
        "stroke-width": 1,
        "class": "analogDrop"
}).on("mouseover", overNode)
.on("mouseout", outNode);
```

If selectedNode is defined, you are over that path.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x17hxgus/17/).